# Splitting on "\n" Java

Tags: java, eclipse, string, list, newline

So I have written my String to a file 
( wrote the "\n"s as "\n" to make them appear as "\n")
But when I get the String back from the file it wont split on the "\n"'s. I know that the string is what I want it to be, but as you can see in this screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6OFM.jpg

the split turns into a list with only one element (which is the whole String, and also why it crashes when I try to get column[1]), and it doesnt split on the "\n"'s.

Can any of you help me figure out why?

Here is the code as displayed in the screenshow (but without the console output)

```
public void loadGame(String boardInput){
    String column[] = boardInput.split("\n");
    System.out.println(column[0]);
    boardWidth = column[1].length();
    for (int y = 0; y < column.length; y++){
        if ( column[y].contains("@") || column[y].contains("+")){
            currentY = y;
        }
        ArrayList<Cell> row = new ArrayList<Cell>();
        String Chars[] = column[y].split("");
        for (int x = 0; x < column[y].length(); x++){
            if ( Chars[x].equals("@") || Chars[x].equals("+")){
                currentX = x;
            }
            if (Chars[x].equals(".") || Chars[x].equals("+") || Chars[x].equals("*")){
                row.add(new Cell(Chars[x], true));
            } else {
                row.add(new Cell(Chars[x], false));
            }
            }
            board.add(row);
    }
}
```

And this is the value of boardInput: `*######*\n#  @   #\n# $  . #\n#      #\n*######*`

Comment: Does `boardInput.split("\\n");` work?

Comment: *"wrote the "\n"s as "\n" to make them appear as "\n""* Why, just why... There aren't enough characters/string out there to use as separators, you had to use precisely `\n`...

Comment: i would try split("\\n"). ...edit: to slow ..

Comment: @m0skit0 - No worries, that's a Markdown formatting issue. Here's what it reads: `( wrote the "\n"s as "\\n" to make them appear as "\n")`

Comment: And btw, you can just use `str.toCharArray()` instead of `column[y].split("")`.

Comment: @ChrisForrence I know, my point is why use "\\n" when you can use anything else...

Comment: @m0skit0 I needed the \n symbol to create a newline in the console, the String is actually a 2d map.

Comment: @ChrisForrence I have tried that but it didn't work :/

Comment: Then you can just use the real newline character...

Comment: @m0skit0 when I just used "\n" it didnt show up in the string I saved in the txt file

Comment: Of course, it's not a visual character, but that doesn't matter. What's the purpose of the file, for you to look at it or the program to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
String column[] = boardInput.split("\\n");
```

`"\n"` is the special character for the "line break". The additional `\` escapes the other `\` so it is read as the text `\n` and not the special character any longer.

Read about [Escape Sequences here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Comment: I have tried this, but the same problem still persists. It wont split.

Answer (score 1):

use `s.split("\\n")` alwas use `\` before special characters.
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=96

Comment: I have tried this, but the same problem still persists. It wont split.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you, and the other answers didn't work for me either.
So I tried this: `.split("\\\\n")` and that worked.  I assume there is something funny with our input that makes the double escaping necessary.